# Custom script rest call in Azure AD B2c

Tags: java, azure, rest

Iam calling rest call in custom policy, Not sending any header or certifciates in rest call.
getting following error..

"Exception": {
"Kind": "Handled",
"HResult": "80131509",
"Message": "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.",
"Data": {},
"Exception": {
"Kind": "Handled",
"HResult": "80131501",
"Message": "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.",
"Data": {}
}

Please help me to resolve above error
I try to send the
true
After adding also ended up with same error

Comment: Sounds like your API endpoint is returning an invalid HTTPS certificate?

Comment: if I do the same call from the postman (my local) , then API is working fine

Comment: There could be a root certificate authority on your pc that Azure AD B2C does not have. If that is the case, you would need a new certificate signed by one of the CAs that B2C does trust.

Comment: Hi Juunas ,  is there any way to turn off SSL validation from custom script while making a rest calls ?

Comment: I don't know. It sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi,
API is running on the gateway server there is no valid certificate present for the same. while API is calling from B2c it is throwing The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure, so is there any way I can access the gateway? As of now rest API is called from custom policies. is there any alternative for the same?